# java ternary operator return function result

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I'm just wondering if it is possible to create something like this:

```
String variable = "name of the variable I'm checking";

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{       // if it's possible what type should the check variable be?
        check = (array[0].equals("value1") || array[0].equals("value2") ? 
                "some value or null?" : throwException(i, variable);
}
```

```
public void throwException(int index, String name) throws TelegrammException
{
    throw new TelegrammException("Wrong telegramm format at position: " 
                                 + index + "; Name: " + name);
}
```

If this is not possible could you suggest a good practice of how to do something similar?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve, but you can't assign the result of a `void` method to a variable.

Comment: how about: if ... else ?

Comment: "If this is not possible" - what did your compiler say when you tried to compile this? There should be your answer to that question. And why would you want to use a ternary expression, rather than an `if` statement, if you do not have two result expressions (but one expression and one "throwing an exception") ?

Comment: I just wanted to shorten the code somehow and was wondering if something like this would be possible. No I didn't try compiling it since I know this wouldn't work, that's why I asked if someone knows a way :)
I currently do have IF & ELSE statements but I have to check 16 variables and that leaves me with 100 lines of IF & ELSE statements...

Comment: You are stuck using something like this: `if (!array[0].equals("value1") && !array[0].equals("value2")) { throw new TelegrammException(); } check = "some value or null?";` within the for loop. Besides, it is barely longer than your code.

Comment: Oh, and... You should stick to the [Java Naming Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Method names always start with **lowercase**.

Comment: just started with Java, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: make your method "return" `String`:

```
public String throwException(int index, String name) throws TelegrammException
{
    throw new TelegrammException("Wrong telegramm format at position: " 
                                 + index + "; Name: " + name);
}
```

Now, this never actually returns a `String` because it doesn't complete normally. But you can now use this in a conditional expression:

```
String result = condition ? "Something" : throwException(index, name);
```

**But**: this is an abuse of syntax. Just stick with a plain old if statement:

```
if (condition) {
    result = "Something";
} else {
    throwException(index, name);
}
```

You might also then want to consider making the return type of the method `TelegrammException`:

```
public TelegrammException throwException(int index, String name) throws ...
```

This allows you to `throw` at the call site:

```
  throw throwException(index, name);
```

which allows you to indicate to the compiler (and humans reading your code) that execution doesn't continue beyond there, which may help you with things like definite assignment/return value requirements.

Answer (score 2):

*Technically* yes if you change the return type of your `throwException` method to `String`.

```
public String throwException(int index, String name) throws TelegrammException
```

However, having a method which ostensibly returns a string which in fact always throws is very unconventional and would almost certainly confuse future readers of your code. The idiomatic way to express your intent is to not use a ternary expression at all:

```
if (array[0].equals("value1") || array[0].equals("value2"))
{
    check = "some value or null?";
}
else
{
    throwException(i, variable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible with ternary operator. At least not in Java. Both expressions should resolved to return the same thing. Otherwise the compiler emits an error. Your second expression is not returning anything apart from the throwing expression. It won't work that way.

[From the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), regarding the ternary operator:

> The first expression must be of type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a `void` method.

You should consider doing it with traditional approach.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{   // if it's possible what type should the check variable be?
    if (array[0].equals("value1") || array[0].equals("value2"))
    { 
        check =   "some value or null?";
    } else {
        throwException(i, variable);
    }
}
```

Comment: "It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method." But it doesn't have to be a void method.

Comment: " Both the expressions should resolved to return the same thing. " - should, but don't _need_ to. `System.out.println("x".equals("y") ? true : "no")` compiles fine. Can't have a void method call obviously, but any resulting type would be fine.

Comment: @daniu indeed. A particularly insidious example I found recently was [`System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(0).equals(true ? Integer.valueOf(0) : Double.valueOf(0)));`](https://ideone.com/7C1wQS).

Comment: @AndyTurner It does look wrong; then again, I guess a variation of `Exception throwMe = Math.random() < 0.5 ? new RuntimeException() : new IOException()` might get used, which isn't that far off type-wise.